# Yum Download (Online Machine) to Install (Offline Machine) Not Working PyQt4

Tags: installation, pyqt4, redhat

I am trying to install PyQt4 on an air-gapped offline machine.

On an online machine I do

```
yum install --downloadonly --directorydir /path/to/store/it PyQt4-devel
```

I then transfer the entire directory to the offline machine.

There I've tried to cd into the directory and do

```
sudo rpm -i *.rpm
```

As well as

```
yum install PyQt4*.rpm
```

Neither one worked, both citing either missing dependencies or in the case of the rpm one 'qt-sqlite < 1:4.7.1-16 is obsoleted by qt-1:4.8.7-9.el7_9.x86_64`

However I thought this method is supposed to pull any dependencies?

Comment: Both Qt4 and PyQt4 are totally obsolete and no longer offficially supported.

Comment: That's great but it doesn't help the problem. This is the version I am required to use for a variety of reasons that aren't really relevant to the question.

Comment: Well, it strongly suggests the onus is now entirely on you to sort out all the dependencies that have been obsoleted by trying to use unsupported software. You might be able to find old, pre-built versions of all the dependencies that are compatible, but if not, the only recourse will be to re-build qt4, sip4, pyqt4, etc from scratch.